# How to do a live UITextField count while typing (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview

I would like to count the character when user keep typing in **UITextField** with swift.

Image of Field and Label:

[image]

I have already placed UITextField and UILabel, just haven't found any information on Stack overflow, also if you can do one in **UITextView** I also appreciate it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To use the function below you need to implement the `UITextFieldDelegate protocol` on the text field you want to count. This gets called every time the `UITextField`s text changes:

Your class declaration should look something like this

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
```

You should have an `@IBOutlet` similar to this

```swift
@IBOutlet var txtValue: UITextField
```

Set the `UITextField` s delegate to `self`.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    txtValue.delegate = self                
}

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let newLength = count(textField.text.utf16) + count(string.utf16) - range.length

    mylabel.text =  String(newLength) // Set value of the label
    // myCounter = newLength // Optional: Save this value
    // return newLength <= 25 // Optional: Set limits on input. 
    return true
}
```

Note that this function is called on all `UITextField`s so if you have several `UITextField`s you will need to add a logic to know witch one is calling this function.

Comment: How to connect it to label? sorry I'm kind of beginner

Comment: Okay I got it, but how to change the small label on bottom of my text field?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what label you are referring to.

Comment: Where is **"142"** in the picture I attached to this question.

Comment: I also add to the answer supposing the label is call mylabel and you have an IBOutlet to it

Comment: Thank you, Works! I will try to figure out UItextview,

Comment: this doesn't seem to get called when pressing the (x) clear search button unfortunately

Answer (score 22):

A very elegant and neat solution exists using UITextFieldDelegate. My solution uses the concept of selectors. In a selector you tell your compiler what function/action to perform when a particular event happens. In this case - typing in textfield. Make sure that you have set the textField delegate in storyboard.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   yourTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
}

@objc func textFieldDidChange(textField : UITextField){
   label.text = yourTextField.text?.count
}
```

Answer (score 13):

For multiple `UITextView`

[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

 @IBOutlet weak var ticketSummaryTV: UITextView!
 @IBOutlet weak var ticketDescriptionTV: UITextView!

 @IBOutlet weak var summaryCountLbl: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var descriptionCountLbl: UILabel!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    ticketSummaryTV.delegate = self
    ticketDescriptionTV.delegate = self

    self.updateCharacterCount()
 }

 func updateCharacterCount() {
    let summaryCount = self.ticketSummaryTV.text.characters.count
    let descriptionCount = self.ticketDescriptionTV.text.characters.count

    self.summaryCountLbl.text = "\((0) + summaryCount)/50"

    self.descriptionCountLbl.text = "\((0) + descriptionCount)/500"
 }

 func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    self.updateCharacterCount()
 }


 func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool{
    if(textView == ticketSummaryTV){
       return textView.text.characters.count +  (text.characters.count - range.length) <= 50
    }else if(textView == ticketDescriptionTV){
        return textView.text.characters.count +  (text.characters.count - range.length) <= 500
    }
    return false
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This will only allow your textfield input 14 char

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.label.text = "14"
    self.textfield.delegate = self
}
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let newLength = count(textField.text.utf16) + count(string.utf16) - range.length
    if(newLength <= 14){
        self.label.text = "\(14 - newLength)"
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
}
}
```

And Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
In Swift
viewDidLoad {
self.yourTextView.delegate = self
self.updateCharacterCount()
}

func updateCharacterCount() {
    self.yourLabel.text = "\((65) - self.yourTextView.text.characters.count)"  
}

func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    self.updateCharacterCount()
}


func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    self.updateCharacterCount()
    return textView.text.characters.count +  (text.characters.count - range.length) <= 65
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5.1

Add `viewController` delegate

```
final class CreditCardViewController : BaseViewController , UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var cvvTextField: UITextField!
```

Add `viewDidLoad()`

```
cvvTextField.delegate = self
```

And add delegate function.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if(textField == cvvTextField){
            let characterCountLimit = 3
            let startingLength = textField.text?.count ?? 0
            let lengthToAdd = string.count
            let lengthToReplace = range.length

            let newLength = startingLength + lengthToAdd - lengthToReplace

            return newLength <= characterCountLimit
        }

        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5.3

Add **UITextFieldDelegate** in you viewController with outlets

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{
     @IBOutlet weak var txtGroupName: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var lblWordCount: UILabel!
```

Add **textfeild delegate** in your **viewDidLoad()** like below

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   txtGroupName.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
  }
    
   @objc func textFieldDidChange(textField : UITextField){
    self.lblWordCount.text = "\(self.txtGroupName.text!.count)/"+"\(65)"
  }
```

We have set also **meximum text limit 65** . you can **replace 65 to what you want**.

```
extension viewController:UITextFieldDelegate{
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if !(textField.text?.isEmpty ?? true){
            return textField.text!.count +  (string.count - range.length) <= 65
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

It's **output** is like below

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it in Swift 3/4.

First, make sure you've got your textField's delegate set in `viewDidLoad`.

```
yourTextField.delegate = self
```

Then, implement `shouldChangeCharactersIn`:

```
extension YourViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textFieldToChange: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
      // limit to 4 characters
      let characterCountLimit = 4

      // We need to figure out how many characters would be in the string after the change happens
      let startingLength = textFieldToChange.text?.characters.count ?? 0
      let lengthToAdd = string.characters.count
      let lengthToReplace = range.length

      let newLength = startingLength + lengthToAdd - lengthToReplace

      return newLength <= characterCountLimit
    } 
}
```

Additional details [here](https://grokswift.com/uitextfield/)

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 for `UITextView` change text event `UITextViewDelegate`

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView` count while typing in Swift:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        let textCount = textView.text?.count ?? 0 + text.count - range.length
        self.textCountLabel.text  = "\(textCount)"
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple...

Add a `UITextViewDelegate` to your class header like this...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate { ... }
```

Add the `@IBOutlet` to both the `UILabel` and the `UITextView` like so...

```
@IBOutlet weak var characterCountLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var characterTextField: UITextView!
```

Then add the following delegate to the `viewDidLoad()` function...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.characterTextField.delegate = self // required for character counter
}
```

Finally, just create a `func` for the `textViewDidChange` delegate method...

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    self.characterCountLabel.text = String("\(textView.text.count)")
}
```

I personally checked and verified this simple way to add a text counter for your `UITextView` and output it to a `UILabel` and it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
 func updateCharacterCount() {
           let count = DescriptionTextview.text.count
           descountlabel.text = "\((0) + count)/140"
       }

extension DescriptionCollectionViewCell: UITextViewDelegate{

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            descountlabel.becomeFirstResponder()
            self.updateCharacterCount()
        }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool{
           let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
           let count = textView.text.count +  (text.count - range.length)
           if count <= 140 {
               return true
           }else{
               generator.notificationOccurred(.error)
               return false
           }
    }

}
```