# Swift 3: Show characters remaining in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I wonder how I can show the characters remaining in a `UITextField`.

Right now I am limiting the characters by:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == TextFieldOne {
         guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
         let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
         return newLength <= 55
    }
    return true
 }
```

What I want to do is to have a `UILabel` that counts down from `55` while you are typing.

I was thinking of adding some sort of logic inside `textFieldDidChange` buy I cant access range from that function.

Comment: It may be better idea to add a label above the UITextField which will hold the number of character remaining.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a live UITextField count while typing (Swift)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656501/how-to-do-a-live-uitextfield-count-while-typing-swift)

Comment: @Larme that is what I want :) - What I want to do is to have a UILabel that counts down from 55 while you are typing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the `UITextFieldDelegate`.

Set the delegate in `viewDidLoad` to the `textField` Outlet.

And then you use the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` function.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textField.delegate = self

        // here you set the start value 55 of your label
        label.text = String(55)
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
        let length = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length

        // create an Integer of 55 - the length of your TextField.text to count down
        let count = 55 - length

        // set the .text property of your UILabel to the live created String
        label.text =  String(count)

        // if you want to limit to 55 charakters
        // you need to return true and <= 55

        return length <= 55 // To just allow up to 55 characters
    }

}
```

Comment: that does now work for me `yourLabel` will print out 56 even tough I only typed in 55 letters

Comment: And it counts up instead of down

Comment: see my edit. it does what you want. i will edit again to add explanation

Comment: Cheers that worked! But why must you add `-1` on the return? Or what I dont get is how the textfield limits the amount of letters you can type but the counter still can increment with one once you hit the limit

Comment: Actually that only let me insert 54 chars. I had to tweak it to this in order to get it to work `guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
            let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
            
            let countValue = 55 - newLength
            
            if countValue >= 0 {
                titleCounter.text = String(countValue)
            }
            
            return newLength <= 55`

Comment: okay maybe i confused something. wanted to provide you the help as soon as possible